# Citations: Reference year right parenthesis not part of reference

Tags: hyperref, citing

I am using the Chicago package and when using the \shortciteN{} command, the right parenthesis around the year is not linked where as the rest of the reference is.  For example, below is my preamble as well as document body...

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[pdftex,a4paper=false,letterpaper=true,colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=brown,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage[left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{chicago}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\shortciteN{allen2013}

\bibliographystyle{chicago}

\bibliography{Bibliography}{}

\end{document}
```

---

My "Bibliography.bib" file looks as follows...

---

```
@article{allen2013,

  title={Accrual reversals, earnings and stock returns},

  author={Allen, Eric J and Larson, Chad R and Sloan, Richard G},

  journal={Journal of Accounting and Economics},

  volume={56},

  number={1},

  pages={113--129},

  year={2013},

  publisher={Elsevier}}
```

---

When I compile, the reference list in the PDF looks fine however the citation in-text appears as follows...

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewgXw.png]

My question is **How can I get the right parenthesis after the year appear as linked like the rest of the reference?**  I have searched these forums meticulously for any information that would help me answer this question with no luck.  I know it can be done without switching to some different package.  I know I can modify the "chicago" package to get the desired effect but how?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `chicago`, but shouldn't `hyperref` be loaded last?

Comment: Off-topic: You should pass the option `letterpaper` to the `geometry` package, and you should not pass the options `pdftex`, `a4paper=false`, and `letterpaper=true` to the `hyperref` package. The option `bookmarks` is "true" by default; hence, I wouldn't specify this option unless I wanted to state `bookmarks=false`. Separately, if all four margins take the same value, it's more straightforward (and easier to debug...) to write `margin=1in` than `left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load `hyperref` after `chicago` (check out [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/89497) for exceptions to the "always load `hyperref` last" rule):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{Bibliography.bib}
@article{allen2013,
title={Accrual reversals, earnings and stock returns},
author={Allen, Eric J and Larson, Chad R and Sloan, Richard G},
journal={Journal of Accounting and Economics},
volume={56},
number={1},
pages={113--129},
year={2013},
publisher={Elsevier}}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{chicago}
\usepackage[pdftex,a4paper=false,letterpaper=true,colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=red,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\shortciteN{allen2013}

\bibliographystyle{chicago}

\bibliography{Bibliography}{}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]